# Get the number of days till today for the current month and current year

Tags: php, date

How To get the number of days that have already passed from the current month and the number of days that have already passed from the current year  eg if today is April 6. 
I should be getting 6 for current month and
I should be getting 97 for current year

Is there a way I can get the same excluding SUNDAYS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the php [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. It has a parameter `'z'`, which is the day of the year, in your situation 97:

```
echo date('z');
```

Same with day of the month:

```
echo date('j');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about getting days of month

Comment: Added it just now, take a look at the docs. You can get a lot out of it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I would have given u +100 for such a simple and nice answer, but y u downvoted me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [getdate](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) function

```
var_dump( getdate() );
```

Will output:

```
array(11) {
  ...
  ["mday"]=>
  int(6)
  ...
  ["yday"]=>
  int(96)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has excellent documentation about this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

The current month in php can be retrieved with `date("n")` and the current day of the year is `date("z")` (starting with zero).

Answer (score 0):

```
$dayNumber = date("z") + 1;
```

date("z") starts counting from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
this will surely help you    
<?php
        $dt = new DateTime;
        if(isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
        $dt->
        setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);}
        else {
        $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
        }
        $year = $dt->format('o');
        $week = $dt->format('W');
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-  1) .   
        '&year='.$year; ?             >">Pre Week</a> 
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.  
        ($week+1).'&year='.$year;  
        ?  >">Next Week</a>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Employee</td>
        <?php
        do{
        echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "      
        </td>\n";
        $dt->modify('+1 day');
        }while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
        ?>
```