# How to get the number of months that the current year has passed(relative to the current date)?

Tags: javascript

So far I only know how to get the current year:

```
const date = new Date()
const year = date.getFullYear() 
=> 2017 <- find how many months have passed in this year relative with the current date
```

I searched on Google and the closest thing I could find was the same question but in [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042268/get-the-number-of-days-till-today-for-the-current-month-and-current-year).

(So for example, this year only has `1` month, since we're in January.)

**Output:**

This is what would you get if you ran the code today Jan 02:

```
{ months: 1 }
```

Comment: Please share some more sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: What have you tried and researched?  Generally SO is for asking about code that doesn't have the expected output, not for asking a question *without trying any code yourself*.

Comment: @gurvinder372 There's no input. just the code I provided. (I added some output).

Comment: Cant you just do `date.getMonth() + 1` ? Its 2018 though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find how many months have passed in this year relative with the
>   current date

Just do `date.getMonths`

```
var monthsElapsed = date.getMonth() + 1;
```